# Barrier voltage and knee voltage are give same meaning?

Tags: voltage, barrier

Is there any difference between barrier voltage and knee voltage? Could somebody please let me know, if any.

Comment: I've never heard of barrier voltage but after quickly googling the definition for barrier voltage they sound like different names for the same thing.

Comment: Depends on bias direction of the diode. But in general, "barrier heighth at equilibrium" (or built-in voltage) refered to semiconductor structure ( doping level of the semiconductors etc), and "knee voltage" refered to the I-V curve of diode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barrier voltage is minimum amount of voltage required to conduct the diode , and Knee voltage is the same [image]

Image Source : Quora

Comment: going to same meaning ,thank u